# Installing signed APK does not install app on Android Wear

Tags: android, wear-os

When I try to install app on Android Wear by installing signed APK on handheld, I receive this error on Wear logcat:

```
0:34:06.143    1874-5212/? E/WearablePkgInstaller﹕ Error finding asset for package: com.company.app
    com.google.android.wearable.gmsclient.WearableException: getDataItem failed: Status{statusCode=TIMEOUT, resolution=null}
            at com.google.android.wearable.gmsclient.GoogleApiClientHelper.throwIfFailed(GoogleApiClientHelper.java:98)
            at com.google.android.wearable.gmsclient.DataManager.getDataItem(DataManager.java:153)
            at com.google.android.clockwork.packagemanager.PackageManagerUtil.getPackageFdForPackageWithName(PackageManagerUtil.java:57)
            at com.google.android.clockwork.home.provider.WearablePackageInfoProvider.openFile(WearablePackageInfoProvider.java:147)
            at android.content.ContentProvider.openAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:1213)
            at android.content.ContentProvider.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:1393)
            at android.content.ContentProvider.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:1459)
            at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:342)
            at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:312)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
    Could not create a temp file from FD for com.company.app
```

Comment: Do your Wear app have the same package as your companion app ?

Comment: Yes it does. Package name are the same

Comment: Both apks are signed with the same key ?

Comment: Yes, signed with same key.

Comment: Your asset folder is in the apk ? Did you check if all the files you're supposed to have are in the folder before and after the build ?

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick check; ensure that the R file is not corrupted, or that nothing is wrong with it. All of the asset based issues that I have had in the past, since the R file is Android's way of assigning asset IDs in the app, are from issues with the R file, which Android Studio, at least earlier, was really bad at updating and keeping fresh.

Comment: I cleaned project, so R is rebuilt, still can't install on wear via mobile.

Answer (score 0):

this problem is google play service lib and android wear app does not match, try to update your android wear app in your phone and update the android version in your watch, finally set boothblue debug over phone enable.
good luck